# where is the source code of the face detection implementation on Android 4.0 Ice cream sandwich？

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-detection

ICS has provided new API for face detection. I traced the source code, but I cannot find how the detection implemented. I found the interface OMXCameraAdapterFillBufferDone, in which I can get how many faces have been detected. but what happened before this?

can anybody tell me where the the source code of face detection implementation is? Thanks!!!

Comment: do you mean `FaceUnlock` source code?